# Webpack, ES6 export/import & Vue.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

I'm in the process of moving the build process of a vue.js app from gulp/browserify/vueify to webpack with vue-loader.

If I have `modules: false` in my `.babelrc`, I get an error on page load:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

If I remove `modules: false`, the errors I get are along the lines of `Vue.use is not a function`. This can be fixed by changing the way I import libraries from:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
```

to

```
var Vue = require('vue').default;
```

#### `webpack.conf.js`

```
var path = require('path');
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf.js');

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/js'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      enforce: 'pre',
      include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
      options: {
        formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: vueLoaderConfig
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: path.posix.join('./dist/img', 'img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

#### So my question is:

Do I have to know ahead of time whether or not a library uses `import`/`export default` or `require`/`module.exports`? Or does webpack take care of that and I assume I can use `import`/`export` instead of `require`/`module.exports` across the board?

Comment: can you share your webpack config?

Comment: @francoisromain Added

Comment: Do you have the same error without using eslint-loader? And what is in `vueLoaderConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write all your code using ES6 and `import/export`. Do not worry about the code in libraries.